# Can I install Microsoft Office Professional 2007 on more than one system?

Tags: license, microsoft-office-2007

I bought Microsoft Office Professional 2007 (for office usage) but I have 3 computers and it's so expensive. Can I buy a single Microsoft Office and install it for more than 1 computer?

It's not mentioning that it's for 1 user only but the salesman in the computer shop told me I have to buy 1 Microsoft Office for each computer so I need 2 more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bought a retail MS Office, that means it's ONE license for ONE computer, but you can change the computer and reinstall it as many times as you want.

So, from e legal point of view, you are allowed to use the software on a single machine at any given time. That computer may have one or more users.

From a technical point of view, you can install it simultaneously on several computers, but that's a breach of the EULA and may have legal consequences for you or for your company.

Comment: thanx, there is many companys use 1 license for many computer , so i'm wonder if anyone will know if i use 1 license for 2 pc? or the other companys they have a special ways to use 1 license without anyone know about them

Comment: There are a hole set of different MS licenses. Usually big companies buy Open Licenses or Volume Licenses. This means, they have one license which permits them to use the same application on several computers.

And now, about the 1 retail license on multiple computers ... it's not legal. You can do it, but if you're company will be checked for software licenses, you will have to pay. Probably, Microsoft also can find out that you are using several computers, because, if I'm not mistaken, Office "calls home" and tells MS some information about your computer (like cpu, memory and hdd SNs)

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is **wrong**. Starting with Office 2007, the retail (traditional disc and box) license allows you to install Office on a primary computer, like a desktop **AND** a portable machine, like a laptop. It stipulates that you must be the primary user on BOTH machines.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/office-2010-license/7e6cefc4-81c7-483b-b889-86909aa7d586